# SQL search on title field with like and custom ordering

Tags: mysql, sqlite, union, union-all

I have a song database and need to implement a search.

I want to produce a list of results where the head of the list is the result of

```
like 'st%'
```

and the rest is the result of

```
like '%st%'
```

If I use UNION it will correctly produce a list with no duplicates, but not in the order I am wanting.

If I use UNION ALL, it will produce the list in the order I want, but having duplicates.

Am I able to use this sort of query, or will I need to do it another way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use case statements in the `order by` clause.  Here is the SQL Standard way of doing this:

```
select *
from songs
where song like '%st%'
order by (case when song like 'st%' then 1 else 0 end) desc,
         song
```

In MySQL, you can just use the expression:

```
order by (song like 'st%') desc, song
```

Because a boolean expression evaluates to 0 (false) or 1 (true).  The `desc` will put the matches first.

By the way, you *CANNOT* depend on the ordering after a `union` or `union all`.  SQL tables are inherently unordered.  SQL results sets are inherently unordered, unless explicitly ordered with an `order by` clause (or a `group by` clause in MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a query to search the database for likenesses of those elements and assign them to variables from that point you can sort them with the appropriate code.

Comment: This is obvious.  My question was to see if this could be done within the sql query.